# Could not find registered compiler for platform CUDA

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tensorflow installed, cuda installed, my program can successfully run on GPU:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 30655 MB memory:
 -> device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM3-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:0c:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
```

(If it matters, I've restricted tensorflow to use just one GPU by writing the following: `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "7"`)

I've ben trying to optimize GPU performance in hope of achieving faster fitting speeds. I was going to follow [this guide on enabling XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla?hl=en), i.e. to define each tf.function with `jit_compile=True`:

```
@tf.function(jit_compile=True)
def ...
```

however I'm stuck with this error:

```
2022-05-29 18:59:56.268562: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:248 :
  UNIMPLEMENTED: Could not find compiler for platform CUDA:
     NOT_FOUND: could not find registered compiler for platform CUDA -- check target linkage
     (hint: try adding tensorflow/compiler/jit:xla_gpu_jit as a dependency)
```

I'm not sure how it's possible that tensorflow can't find a compiler for CUDA, since without XLA everything works okay.

Also, I'm not really experienced in this area, so I couldn't make any sense of the "hint" (see above in the error message)

<sup>Before you ask me how's it possible that I'm noob in ML but has this powerful GPU - I don't own it, I'm just working with the Nvidia DGX machine provided by my university</sup>

Comment: It seems to contain only one gpu device . Could you set cuda visible devices like below.                                                                  
 os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"  // You can skip it too.